# CanCan has_many through, specific abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm currently making a project using devise and cancan.

To understand my problem i have this models :

**User** with some attributes and is_admin boolean to global access

**Role** belongs_to project and user with a specific ability for user on each project

**Project** has_many some others models user can edit or not (depend of it's role on the project)

So my question is how can I do this ?

Actually I have this Ability class :

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    if user
      can :read, :all                   # allow everyone to read everything
      if user.is_admin?
        can :manage, :all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I need to manage role in models depend on my Project model or something else ? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    if user
      can :read, :all                   # allow everyone to read everything
      if user.is_admin?
        can :manage, :all
      end
      can manage, Project do |project|
          project.users.include? user
          #projects.users return the list of the users in the the role table.
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can customize it but I think it's the good way to start.

Comment: Is there no way to do like `can :manage, Project, :user_ids => user.id` ?

Comment: I guess you can just replace the line "project.users.include? user" with "user_ids.include? user.id"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaner way to organize your Ability.rb.

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # Set user to blank User.new if user isn't logged in.  

  # Everyone, including guests, can read everything
  can :read, :all

  # Will only let user manage if @project.admin_id == user.id 
  can :manage, Project, admin_id: user.id 

end
```